# Updated to ios13; got black font

Tags: iphone, ios

Having recently updated to ios 13 the app labels are now black, along with the lock screen clock, date, etc. How does one change the color back to white? I have tried toggling between dark./light theme and searching settings, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: added screenshot
[lock screen with black text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad2yk.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Your question is difficult to understand.  Would you say that the screen colors are inverted?  If so, have you tried `Accessibility -> Display & Text Size` and changing the "Smart Invert" and "Classic Invert"?

Comment: Not so much the screen colors inverted, only the text color. “Smart Invert” does not change this. The app labels refer to the text under each app’s icon on the home screen. I’ve updated the original question with a screenshot of the lock screen with the black text.

Comment: @glopes You're replying to my comment from 6 months ago and before the question was edited with a screenshot to add clarification.  As someone reading this who has not experienced this issue, it was difficult to understand.  You've experienced it first-hand so, of course, it makes sense.  OP's need to write questions to explain exactly what's happening because we're not looking over their shoulder when the problem happens.

Comment: I see, I've deleted my previous comment, but want to keep the comment that this only kicks in after you reboot your phone. I spent months without a reboot, and had to do it just now and immediately got this annoying black font!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the color is chosen based on the color of background image, i.e. dark bg = white text, light bg = black text.

Comment: This used to be the case but not anymore. As soon as you get stuck in this crazy mode, you can switch to a black background, and what it will do is switch to a dark brown color that is kind of visible but extremely annoying! No easy way out at the moment, absolutely horrible!